# Merge Sort Algorithm Code

Tags: java, mergesort

This is code for Merge Sort using the Java programming language.
Where there is an error, it does not give me the correct output.
Is it possible to help me to resolve?  Thank you.

I want to work with arrays of type integer.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Excersize5 {

    public void MergeSort(int[] Arr) {
        int N = Arr.length;
        if (N > 1) {
            int Middle = (N) / 2;
            int[] A1 = LeftElement(Arr);
            int[] A2 = RightElement(Arr);
            MergeSort(A1);
            MergeSort(A2);
            Merge(Arr, A1, A2);
        }
    }

    public void Merge(int[] Result, int[] A1, int[] A2) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < Result.length; k++) {
            if (A1[i] >= A2[j] || (i < A1.length &&
                    A1[i] <= A2[j])) {
                Result[k] = A1[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                Result[k] = A2[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] LeftElement(int[] Total) {
        int NL = Total.length / 2;
        int[] L = new int[NL];
        for (int p = 0; p < NL; p++) {
            L[p] = Total[p];
        }
        return L;
    }

    public int[] RightElement(int[] Total) {
        int NL = Total.length / 2;
        int NR = Total.length - NL;
        int[] R = new int[NR];
        for (int q = 0; q < NR; q++) {
            R[q] = Total[q];
        }
        return R;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Excersize5 e5 = new Excersize5();
        int[] r = {5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 7};
        e5.MergeSort(r);
        System.out.print(r);

    }
}
```

**Output**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>   at practical4.Excersize5.Merge(Excersize5.java:22) at
>   practical4.Excersize5.MergeSort(Excersize5.java:14) at
>   practical4.Excersize5.MergeSort(Excersize5.java:13) at
>   practical4.Excersize5.MergeSort(Excersize5.java:12) at
>   practical4.Excersize5.main(Excersize5.java:55) Java Result: 1 BUILD
>   SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: Yes , I can , This is output Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at practical4.Excersize5.Merge(Excersize5.java:22)
 at practical4.Excersize5.MergeSort(Excersize5.java:14)
 at practical4.Excersize5.MergeSort(Excersize5.java:13)
 at practical4.Excersize5.MergeSort(Excersize5.java:12)
 at practical4.Excersize5.main(Excersize5.java:55)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: This is a homework question! This should not be on here.

Comment: I'll give you a hint:  The 'splitting' of the source array happens virtually by picking a subrange of indices.  You shouldn't actually create new arrays during the splitting step.  You should only have 2 arrays total:  The original, and a temporary one to hold the merged values.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a Vector instead will make it much easier to do. It's because your calling things outside your array length, all of them, and you never return the array result which you should do in some method